# WolframConnector - getting credentials for GoogleCustomSearch

Tags: searching, webservices

I need to fill in the information for the WolframConnector in the panel shown below which is activated by running the command:

```
ServiceConnect["GoogleCustomSearch"]
```

[image]

I have created a Google Custom search engine and from the site URL Basics tab can get the "Custom search engine ID" by clicking on its tab but cannot see how to get the "API key".

Where can I find the correct API key referred to in the panel?.

I am trying to evaluate the following:

```
results = ServiceExecute["GoogleCustomSearch", "Search", 
  {"Query" -> "Orion spacecraft", "FileType" -> Except["png"], 
   "MaxItems" -> 5, "SearchType" -> "Image"}]; 

results[All, {1, 2, 6, 7}]
```

but without proper authentication I cannot replicate the result.

Comment: [Custom Search Engine (free edition) users can obtain the key from the Google Developers Console.](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#prerequisites)

Answer (score 2):

You can see the answer in [this Wolfram Community post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/584226?p_p_auth=SIsOtu3Z)

Basically:

To get the API Key you first have to go to https://console.developers.google.com and create a project if you don't have one yet. Once you have the project (asuming you are using the new console interface), click the Credentials menu at the left. There you'll see all your credentials. If don't have one, click the Add credentials and, for GoogleCustomSearch, you need the API key Browser key type.

For the Custom search engine ID, you have to go to https://cse.google.com/all and add a search engine. Once you create it, just click on that and you'll get a screen with a lot of options. There's a button there that says Search engine ID. Click it and you'll get the ID you need.

Comment: It would be better if you at least summarize the contents of the post you linked to.

Comment: Edited to add summary.